# Php unknown error

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

```
<?php
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","uplod");
    if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    } else{
        echo work
        $sql ="UPDATE tea SET name = ' 8req'  WHERE id = '3 ' "or die ("cant update" . mysql_error());
        if($sql)
            echo"working";
    }
?>
```

Can anyone tell me what's the error in the script?

It isn't updating the db, I tried in phpmyadmin  query is working fine. This is what I wrote in sqlquery:

```
(UPDATE tea SET name = ' 8req' WHERE id = '3 ')
```

[Here I uploaded the video](https://www.screenr.com/embed/kK6N).

Comment: You need to tell us what's the problem (PHP log/console/web output) and what you've tried to solve the problem.

Comment: `echo work` should be `echo 'work';`. Besides, there is no `or die()` when assigning string to a variable and you're not executing the query *at all*.

Comment: What does this have to do with [tag:asp-classic]?

Answer (score 2):

Use this code you didn't add `mysqli_query`.

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","uplod");
if(mysqli_connect_error())
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
else
{
    $sql ="UPDATE tea SET name = ' 8req'  WHERE id = '3 ' ";
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die ("cant update" . mysqli_error($con));
    if($result)
        echo"working";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add else for see if the sql not give result like

> > If($sql) {
> >
> > Echo "working";
> >
> > }else{
> >
> > Echo "not working";
> >
> > }

Or if you use chrome you can inspect elemen before submit and after submit u can clicks action url in network tab for see hiden error

Hope  this help

Answer (score -3):

```
echo 'work';
        $sql =mysql_query("UPDATE tea SET name = ' 8req'  WHERE id = '3 ' ")or die ("cant update" . mysql_error());
        if($sql)
            echo"working";
```

Modify your query.. $sql variable needs a value to compare.

Comment: Don't use mysql_*  its deprecated.